# Matplotlib cannot find Font family [u'sans-serif']

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, fonts, anaconda

I installed matplotlib 2.2.3 using anaconda (with python 2.7.16). I always have this missing font problem on the higher versions of matplotlib (> 1.5.1).

```
/home/satadru/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1331: UserWarning: findfont: Font family [u'serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I know there are many solutions available on the web but nothing solved my problem. I already tried the following suggestions, but none of them helped:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts -qq
sudo apt install font-manager
rm ~/.cache/matplotlib -fr
```

I just don't want to go back to an older version of matplotlib again just to avoid the problem. Please help. My code is

```
 from matplotlib import rcParams
 rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
 rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Tahoma']

 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 .......................
```

Comment: what is your OS? Does the error also occur when you exclude `rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Tahoma']`? I guess yes? I would guess the error comes from the `'sans-serif'` string, that python 2.7 does not seem to understand.

Comment: Yes, still getting the problem after commenting out `rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Tahoma']` . My  primary OS is ubuntu 18.04. Getting this  problem in 2 desktops, 1 laptop. I am also getting the same problem on my macbook where I installed everything using anaconda. I get no issue in matplotlib 1.5.3, but this problem arise in anything higher than that. I am so frustrated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried multiple preambles, some recommended on official matplotlib page:
    
     `fontProperties={'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica'],
    'weight' : 'normal', 'size' : 14}
    from matplotlib import rc
    rc('font',**fontProperties)
    #for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
    rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
    rc('text', usetex=True)`

Comment: does it also happen with python 3.x?

Comment: I did not try that, but my earlier codes are not compatible with python 3.x. I really don't want to switch to python3 now. Besides, I find that this is a major issue, should be fixed anyway.

Comment: When I use Times New Roman instead of Helvetica or Palatino or Tahoma it works!! But can I use Helvetica in some way?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `Tahoma` cannot be found on your system (when I run the code it works fine on matplotlib 2.2.3 with python 2.7 and Tahoma font installed). It's pretty hard to know why `Tahoma` cannot be found on your system, so any information you can provide in this respect might help here.